# alternate row coloring scheme with nested lists

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've a nested list so is the selector thats very specific, is there something wrong with it, cause I see the background green with all list items irrespective it's odd or even.

adding some more html code as per the request

```
.detail ul.table-view li.table-view-cell ul.cell li:nth-child(even) .session {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.detail ul.table-view li.table-view-cell ul.cell li:nth-child(odd) .session {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table-view"> <!-- ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | filter:{keynote:isKeynote} -->
    <li class="table-view-cell" ng-repeat="session in sessions">
        <ul class="cell">
            <li class="cell-content">
                <span class="time" style="background-color:#{{session.color}}">
                  abc
                </span>
                <span class="session">
                    <div>name </div>
                    <div>Room 1</div>
                </span>
            </li>
          <li class="cell-content">
                <span class="time" style="background-color:#{{session.color}}">
                  abc
                </span>
                <span class="session">
                    <div>name </div>
                    <div>Room 1</div>
                </span>
            </li>
          <li class="cell-content">
                <span class="time" style="background-color:#{{session.color}}">
                  abc
                </span>
                <span class="session">
                    <div>name </div>
                    <div>Room 1</div>
                </span>
            </li>
          <li class="cell-content">
                <span class="time" style="background-color:#{{session.color}}">
                  abc
                </span>
                <span class="session">
                    <div>name </div>
                    <div>Room 1</div>
                </span>
            </li>
          <li class="cell-content">
                <span class="time" style="background-color:#{{session.color}}">
                  abc
                </span>
                <span class="session">
                    <div>name </div>
                    <div>Room 1</div>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here's my DOM

```
<ul class="table-view"> <!-- ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | filter:{keynote:isKeynote} -->
    <li class="table-view-cell" ng-repeat="session in sessions">
        <ul class="cell">
            <li class="cell-content">
                <span class="time" style="background-color:#{{session.color}}">
                    <div class="start">{{session.start | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                    <div class="to">to</div>
                    <div class="end">{{session.end | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                </span>
                <span class="session">
                    <div>{{session.name}}</div>
                    <div>Room: {{session.room}}</div>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit - Fixing the HTML, divs only for nesting elements and spans for text.**

```
<ul class="table-view"> <!-- ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | filter:{keynote:isKeynote} -->
        <li class="table-view-cell" ng-repeat="session in sessions">
            <ul class="cell">
                <li class="cell-content">
                    <div class="time" style="background-color:#{{session.color}}">
                        <span>{{session.start | date:"h:mma"}}</span>
                        <span>to</span>
                        <span>{{session.end | date:"h:mma"}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="session" >
                        <span class="name">{{session.name}}</span>
                        <span class="room">Room: {{session.room}}</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Need to see the rendered HTML. Example?

Comment: why not add a class at render time using something like ng-class-odd or ng-class-even: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd

Comment: man, this is what we call lateral thinking... awesome, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `<span>` incorrectly as they should only be used to encapsulate text. Use `<div>` when nesting elements.

I tested the code with `<div>` and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/kjmycq2y/

Comment: thanks for the enlightenment, please see my edit to critic if I've laid down my html correctly, the code on your fiddle works but I'm still having issues, I'm comparing the two to find the difference, need a second eye please

Comment: @Papa your fiddle is not doing it right if the number of rows is not even in every sub-list. See this fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/ean98x0b/